# Ubuntu LTS 16.04 memory usage rises as lag increases

Tags: 16.04, ram, swap

I have a computer with a Intel Core i3 and 4GB of RAM. I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS but am unable to understand why after 4 to 5 hours run time it keeps getting slow and slower until it gets totally stuck unless restarted. At that stage the memory was full and swap was in use. If I compare this with Windows, no such thing happens on my Windows machine.

I have taken a few screenshots having around 10-15 seconds interval and not using any thing but memory keeps rising.

Is there any solution to this problem or I have to increase my swap which 4GB right now?

[image]
[image]
[image]

**UPDATE**

```
sshaider@SSH-Lenovo:~$ cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.swappiness
60
sshaider@SSH-Lenovo:~$
```

few are more screenshots I took right now
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Looking at your screenshots, it seems that you were indeed doing something. You should really inspect this again without all of the applications shown in the screenshot running (browser, webserver, IDE,...). Also, is that Java application you are writing running? May that be slowly filling your memory? Does any process use suspicious amounts of memory?

Comment: Your swap is almost unused. Have you changed the default swappiness value? Please [edit] your question and add the output of `cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.swappiness`. In any case, what you describe is almost certainly a memory leak in one of the programs you are running. Check `top` or that GUI system monitor you show and see what processes are taking up the most RAM.

Comment: @danzel sir as per your direction i tested with all applications closed and results are far better,I have taken few more screen shots,and yes yesterday my application was running,but when i started taking snapshots i was just stuck to the monitor screen but yes you were right system was not idle,

Comment: @terdon no i didnt change any value, and as per your instruction I have edit the question with the command you gave me, i got 60 as a result

Comment: @danzel terdon you both said it seems to be a memory leak issue , but as a learner i want to make one point clear that in case my java application causing a memory leak, so jvm has been assigned a certain amount of memory that can be occupied by memory leak in my app and need to show OutOfMemoryException, but why and how it consumes all  memory but not giving OOM exception?

Comment: @ssh you wont get OOM before you're truly out of memory - including full swap space.